# Separate H2 database for JUnit in Servlets and JDBC

Tags: servlets, jdbc, junit, mockito, h2

I can`t find info how to set up separate H2 db for JUnit in servlets. All info about Spring, but i need H2 to test my DAO and controllers in Servlets app. Will be glad about any info.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with a bit weird way. In my AuthorService DAO class i created constructor which take a connection. And depends on the situation i inject right connetion with AbstractFactory.